# dismissViewControllerAnimated not working when presenter leads to multiple segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, segue

To wire multiple segues to a single button, I use a method similar to [ios - Connect one UIButton to 2 segues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553141/ios-connect-one-uibutton-to-2-segues), which works fine.
The problem is that when I call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

nothing happens. This works fine for me when I had a one to one relationship. But now for whatever reason, the presented VC is not dismissing.

Comment: Is the second seque pushed or it is modal?  When i tried to recreate this with storyboard and connected it created one modal segue and the other is push.  I had to change it to modal manually.  The one that push didn't segue back.

Comment: @Yan, that's exactly what happened. thanks.